# NGINX Rewrite is encoding querystring as a path

Tags: nginx

I want to rewrite internally several locations `/customers/foo?bar=2` to an existing location in my nginx configuration at `/blah` so that it's as if the request was to `/blah/customers/foo?bar=2`.

```
location /blah {
  # View in fiddler
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
  # Lots of config here I don't want to repeat everywhere else
}
location /customers/ {
  rewrite ^/customers/(.*) /blah/customers/$1$is_args$args;
}
location /other/ {
  rewrite ^/other/(.*) /blah/other/$1$is_args$args;
}
# etc...
```

Nginx is rewriting the URL with the querystring encoded as a path `/blah/customers/foo%34bar=2`.

The same thing happens with `rewrite ^ /blah$request_uri;`. It encodes the `?` as `%3F` effectively garbling the URL.

If I do a client redirect `rewrite ^ /blah$request_uri permanent;` the URL is correct and contains the `?` but I want an **internal redirect** inside my NGINX config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$is_args$args`, because the [`rewrite` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) will automatically append any existing query string.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/customers/(.*) /blah/customers/$1 last;
```

Although, I would prefer:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /blah$1 last;
```

Or even:

```
rewrite ^ /blah$uri last;
```